# Custom validation, error message can't display

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an order form where my users are suposed to validate the conditions of sales to proceed  to payment.

If the user hasn't checked the box, I want him to be warned to do so..

I just don't manage to do that...

> Update (add the shopping cart)

the order is initialzed in a shooping cart:

```
class ShoppingCart

  delegate :sub_total, to: :order

  def initialize(token:)
    @token = token
  end

  def order
    @order ||= Order.find_or_initialize_by(token: @token, status: 0) do |order|
      order.sub_total = 0
    end
  end
end
```

the form in  orders/new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @order, url: clients_checkout_path do |f| %>
  <div class="<%= 'error_message' if @order.errors.full_messages.any? %> ">
   <% if  @order.errors.any? %>
     <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
     <% end %>
    <% end %>
 </div>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
  <%= f.input :cgos_accepted, as: :boolean, checked_value: true, unchecked_value: false %>
  <%= f.submit, class: "btn btn-main btn-block" %>
<% end %>
```

here is the controller:

```
class Clients::OrdersController < Clients::ApplicationController

    def index
        @orders = Order.all
        @orders = @orders.filter_by_status(params[:status]) if params[:status]
    end

    def show
        @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @order = current_cart.order
        @billing_address = BillingAddress.new
    end

    def create
        @order = current_cart.order
        @order.update_sub_total!
        @order.update_total!
        if @order.update_attributes!(order_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))
        redirect_to new_clients_order_payment_path(@order)
        end
    end

    private

    def order_params
        params.require(:order).permit(:status,  :user_id, :token , :sub_total, :cgos_accepted)
    end
end
```

in my order model I added a validation:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  validate :accept_cgos, on: :update
  #[...]
  private 

  def accept_cgos
    if self.cgos_accepted == false
      errors.add(:base, :must_accept_cgos)
    end
  end
end
```

my yml file is:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        order:
          attributes:
            base:
              must_accept_cgos: Please accept the general condition of sales
```

I was expecting the warning message to be displayed in the div but it is opening Better Error and says:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid at /clients/cart/checkout
Validation failed: Please accept the general condition of sales
```

So it's kinda working but why isn't it displaying in my error div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `update_attributes!`

You are using the bang-version of `update_attributes`, `update_attributes!`. Just like `save!` and `create!` it will throw an exception when saving is unsuccessful.

If you remove the exclamation mark in that method call, `update_attributes` will return false when being unable to save, instead.

#### Rendering the error

The other part that is missing is rendering the `new` template in case of a validation error. If `update_attributes` returns `true`, a redirect will take place, but if it returns `false`, rails will attempt to render `create.html.erb` by default. But the `new` template can be also used in this case but rails has to be told to do so.

#### Code changes

The changed implementation might then look like this.

```
 if @order.update_attributes(order_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id)) # no bang
    redirect_to new_clients_order_payment_path(@order)
 else
   @billing_address = BillingAddress.new                                   # because the #new template requires it.
   render :new
 end
```

Comment: Okay that's better... and what about displaying my error message? It doesn't appear

Comment: As `@order.update_attributes(order_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))` is `false` the redirect to the new action is not triggered (why does it take the @order variable as a parameter, btw.?). Instead it will render `orders/create.html.erb` (not `new`) which is not shown in the question and might lack the error message handling.

Comment: You mean this redirection ? `redirect_to new_clients_order_payment_path(@order)` it's for the payment...

Comment: Okay you tak eme to the good way I added this in my create action `if @order.update_attributes(order_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))
     redirect_to new_clients_order_payment_path(@order)
    else
     render :new, alert: 'Woooops something went wrong'
  end`

Answer (score 1):

> why isn't it displaying in my error div?

Because of your `create` action, you're doing the `redirect_to`, the `redirect_to` flush the `order` instance and all your errors from object is vanished, try to add `render :new` instead.

```
# for example
def create
  if @order.updated
    redirect_to path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```